# From NSArray to Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an NSArray, called retAlbumArray, which goes like this:

```
(
    {
    coverable = 1;
    "mer_thumb" = "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b6fb29d2786.jpg";
},
    {
    coverable = 0;
    "mer_thumb" = "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b716368a84f.jpg";
},
    {
    coverable = 0;
    "mer_thumb" = "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b71f59cd6b3.jpg";
},
    {
    coverable = 0;
    "mer_thumb" = "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b7241fcfe50.jpg";
},
    {
    coverable = 0;
    "mer_thumb" = "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b73d9e2790e.jpg";
}    )
```

I want to convert the NSArray into array of strings which contains only the value against the key "mer_thumb" so I could have the following:

```
["http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b6fb29d2786.jpg", "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b716368a84f.jpg", "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b71f59cd6b3.jpg", "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b7241fcfe50.jpg", "http://www.abcd.org/Uploads/Images/mer_album/56b73d9e2790e.jpg"]
```

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but this should work:

```
if let array = retAlbumArray.valueForKey("mer_thumb") as? [String] {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
retAlbumArray.map({ element in
    element["mer_thumb"] as? String
})
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer as it is more "Swifty" than mine, though the array returned by the map function as is will be of type `[AnyObject?]`.

Comment: @rog you can fix that with `element["mer_thumb"] as? String`  I'd also recommend using `flatMap` instead of just map as that will eliminate any entries with nil values.